# I can not find out why my code is skipping some .JPG images, can you figure it out?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, png, jpeg

I have a code that converts .jpg and .jpeg files from one folder to .png files.

very simple, but yet very frustrating because it skips some files and does not convert them. I have tried everything but cant seem to find the error and rely on a help of someone from stackoverflow...

```
images_list = os.listdir(path_dir)



def Checker(directory, filename):
    if filename.split(".")[-1] == "jpg":
        print("File found and going trough:" + filename)
        im1 = Image.open(directory + "/" + filename)
        # Define the png_filename variable before using it
        png_filename = filename.strip(".jpg") + '.png'
        im1.save(directory + "/" + png_filename)
        # Remove the original JPEG image from the directory
        os.remove(directory + "/" + filename)
        images_list.remove(filename)

    elif filename.split(".")[-1] == "jpeg":
        print("File found and going trough:" + filename)
        im1 = Image.open(directory + "/" + filename)
        # Define the png_filename variable before using it
        png_filename = filename.strip(".jpeg") + '.png'
        im1.save(directory + "/" + png_filename)
        # Remove the original JPEG image from the directory
        os.remove(directory + "/" + filename)
        images_list.remove(filename)

for item in images_list:
    Checker(path_dir, item)
```

Comment: can you list directory contents and which files are being ignored ? Also You should NEVER modify the list while iterating over it. Remove `images_list.remove(filename)`  from both places and and see the results

Comment: "jpg" != "JPEG" != "jPeG"

Comment: @harshraj22 removing that line solved my issue...

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think it is better to use glob here. Search for all the files with extension .jpg or .jpeg and change the extension.

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

for file in glob.glob('./images/*.jpg')+glob.glob('./images/*.jpeg'):
    Image.open(file).convert('RGB').save(file.rstrip('.jpeg')+'.png', "PNG")
```